# Updating user session using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, session, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have a application which required some external inputs to test application, but this data can only available when user logged in, so when user logged in to system his credential is stored in session to reuse again and to avoid user to login again. Now, the catch we have third party tool for user login and that is in applet which does not work with selenium webdriver.

My requirement is, can we store user logged in session in current user session. That is, first I will log in manually and fetch the session value for user credential. Now, those credential session value I will save in file and will read in java, but how to send those value in session through selenium webdriver with java?

I would appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
Karim Narsindani

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoteWebDriver class from WebDriver Api to set the session, method you are looking at is setSessionId()

Refer to-

protected void setSessionId(java.lang.String opaqueKey)

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html